# Cython: create struct and only keep pointer to it

Tags: cython

In cython, I would like to create a struct in memory and only keep a pointer to it. When I try to do that, I get a "Taking address of non-lvalue"-error.

```
cdef struct mystructtype:
    int foo
    int bar

cdef compute():
    cdef mystructtype* elem
    elem = &mystructtype(2, 3)
```

How to go about this?
(What I'm trying to do is to have a stack of pointers to structs. Right now I have the structs themselves on the stack, but the program is running too slow)

Comment: I don't think it's possible in cython or c, you have to create a lvalue and take its address: `cdef mystructtype* elem   cdef mystructtype s = mystructtype(2, 3)   elem = &s` or `cdef mystructtype* elem = <mystructtype*>malloc(sizeof(mystructtype))`, then manipulate the pointer(don't forget to free the malloced pointer)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your option 1 doesn't work for me because I want to create several elements of mystructtype (at compile time number is unknown), but if I create them all as "s", the address will stay the same.
In the meantime I found out about your option 2 (I'm new to cython) and it's a nice workaround, but (as you hinted at) I managed to create a memory leak which I'm currently trying to fix. So thanks again!

Comment: well, it's easy to delegate the memory management to python in cython. See [Memory Allocation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html). Additionally, [`cymem`](https://github.com/explosion/cymem) is a small but useful tool that might help you.

Comment: Hmm, but if I understand this correctly, using PyMem_Malloc will not actually make sure that the object is deleted once I have no references to it anymore, right? So what do you mean with "delegating memory management to python"?
cymem looks like a useful tool but it doesn't seem to fit my particular use case.

Comment: @Maltimore You do understand correctly - they won't be deleted automatically. You have at least two good options for freeing the memory: 1) if the lifetime is known then you wrap it in a `try` and put the `free` in the `finally` block. 2) You tie the memory to a `cdef class` with the `free` in the destructor (and Python does the reference counting for the `cdef` class).

Comment: @DavidW thanks for your answer as well! I couldn't really work that into my current implementatin though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this question: I did not find a way to do what I wanted to do (and neither did anyone else), so I resorted to working with malloc.